# Writing hive Query output to a HDFS file

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive

I have tested writing hive query output to a file  by executing hive queries inside shell script  using hive –e and hive –f options. when i tried  executing the shell script from putty it is working fine, however in the hue box from oozie workflow the same shell script is not writing any results to local file.

2. Using Insert overwrite directory I can directly write hive query output to a directory inside HDFS however for each query it creates a new directory so I can not use this option.

Please suggest me any alternative option to write multiple hive query output to a single file by executing shell script from oozie workflow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why INSERT OVERWRITE and not just INSERT?

Comment: By the way, INSERT OVERWRITE will create *multiple* files in the general case (i.e multiple mappers and no reducer, or multiple reducers). Hadoop is about distributed computing. If you don't want distributed computing, just stick to MySQL or MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

When running shell action via Oozie workflow, it will run on any of the datanodes. check the output path is present in the datanode